# Wordpress: create a query object from another query object

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following query:

```
$tot_posts = new WP_Query(array(... 'posts_per_page' => -1));
$tot_posts_arr=(array)$tot_cures;
$posts_num=count($tot_cures_arr['posts']);
```

Here, I am counting all of the posts that fit certain parameters. Now, I would like to display all of these posts in a paginated way. Currently, I am just querying again like so:

```
$display_posts = new WP_Query(array(... 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $page));
```

However, I think that querying twice is slowing down the page load. I am wondering if there is some way for me to turn the original query object ($tot_posts) into the second query object ($display_posts).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to grab the total number of pages in order to use pagination in WordPress.

WordPress itself does the majority of the grunt work for you, you can just grab the number of posts you want, along with the current page, and then use `next_posts_link` and `previous_posts_link` functions to display the next and previous links, if necessary.

There's information about this in the [WordPress Codex for WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not clear on what you are trying to say. Are you referring to the first query? Are you trying to say that it is unnecessary? If so, I have my own custom pagination bar that I have built. I need to know the total number of posts.

Comment: Ah, well `WP_Query` was designed to handle the pagination itself, so I guess you either need to extend the functionality of that with filters, or do the two queries like you already are.

Comment: Right, but I am wondering if there is any way to build a query object. If I have the first query, I should be able to turn it into an array of posts and select the ones I need for the page. I am wondering if I can turn a list of posts into a query object. Or, alternatively into some object or array that can be used for the wordpress loop. That way, I would not have to query twice.